# Nodejs loop confusion

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous

I am not able to get the expected result and instead the result is very confusing.. maybe some callback magic or some asynchronous will do magic here...

```
app.post('/upload', function (req, res) {
  var phone_add = req.body.phone_add;
  whatsapp = phone_add.split(',');
  var i=0;

  for (i=0;i<whatsapp.length;i++) {
    message(whatsapp[i],i);
  }
});

function message(whatsapp,i) {
  var mess = "\"Test automation\"";

  console.log(whatsapp);
  command = "yowsup-cli.py -s " +whatsapp+" "+mess+" -c config.txt";

  child = exec(command,function (error, stdout, stderr) {
    if (error !== null) {
      console.log('exec error: ' + error);
      console.log(command);
    }
    else
      console.log("Success! "+i+"  "+command);
  });
}
```

**Output of above ->**

```
919999999999

919222222222

919111111111

Success! 2  yowsup-cli.py -s 919111111111 "Test automation" -c config.txt

Success! 0  yowsup-cli.py -s 919111111111 "Test automation" -c config.txt

Success! 1  yowsup-cli.py -s 919111111111 "Test automation" -c config.txt
```

**whereas Expected output by me->**

```
919999999999

919222222222

919111111111

Success! 2  yowsup-cli.py -s 919999999999 "Test automation" -c config.txt

Success! 0  yowsup-cli.py -s 919222222222 "Test automation" -c config.txt

Success! 1  yowsup-cli.py -s 919111111111 "Test automation" -c config.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

You didn't declare `command`, so node.js is assuming it's a global variable, and it writes over that global variable each time you call `message()`. To fix it, use `var`.

```
var command = "yowsup-cli.py -s " +whatsapp+" "+mess+" -c config.txt";
//^ add var keyword
```

Comment: thank you so much! i was scratching my head over this for past 2 days :p